# Grouped Product won't be added to cart and there is a message "Please specify the quantity of product(s)."

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I am developing a store and the product I tried to add is a grouped product which I had done some design and configuration on the front end. Then, I added sample grouped product and when I click "Add to cart" , there is message "Please specify the quantity of product(s)."

Please see the website (Sorry the website is in Thai but you can try to increase the Quantity of each product and then click add to cart - Pink button)

http://www.preciosathailand.com/eyeline-0001.html

This is PHP code that I made the configuration

```
<?php if ($_hasAssociatedProducts): ?>
<?php foreach ($_associatedProducts as $_item): ?>
    <?php $_finalPriceInclTax = $this->helper('tax')->getPrice($_item, $_item->getFinalPrice(), true) ?>
    <tr>
        <td width="80%"><span class="product-<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></span></td>
        <?php if ($this->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)): ?>
        <td class="a-right">
            <?php if ($this->getCanShowProductPrice($_item)): ?>
            <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true) ?>
            <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml($_item) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </td>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
        <td class="a-center" width="20%">
        <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()) : ?>
            <div class="qty-tools">
                <div class="minus-qty minus-<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>"><a class="click-to-minus" id="minus-<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" href="#" data-id-p="<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>">-</a></div>
                <div class="input-qty-wrapper">
                <input type="text" name="super_group[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>]" data-qty-product-id="<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $_item->getQty()*1 ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Qty')) ?>" class="input-text qty" />
                </div>
                <div class="plus-qty plus-<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>"><a class="click-to-plus" href="#" id="plus-<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" data-id-p="<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>">+</a></div>
            </div>
        <?php else: ?>
            <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </td>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php else: ?>
   <tr>
       <td colspan="<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>4<?php else : ?>3<?php endif; ?>"><?php echo $this->__('No options of this product are available.') ?></td>
   </tr>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This is jQuery that I have done.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('.click-to-minus').click(function(){


        var IDInput = jQuery(this).data('id-p');
        var CurrentVal = jQuery('input[name="super_group['+IDInput+']"]').val();
        var minusedVal = CurrentVal-1;

        jQuery('input#'+IDInput).val(minusedVal);

    });


    jQuery('.click-to-plus').click(function(){

        var pIDInput = jQuery(this).data('id-p');
        var CurrentPlusVal = jQuery('input[name="super_group['+pIDInput+']"]').val();
       /* if ( CountPlus == 0){

            var plusedVal = 1;

        }else{
            jQuery('input#'+pIDInput).val('');
            var plusedVal = CurrentPlusVal+1;
        }*/

        var plusedVal = +CurrentPlusVal+1;
        jQuery('input[data-qty-product-id="'+pIDInput+'"]').val(plusedVal);


    }); 


});
```

Did I do anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to group configurable products, then you should know that magento doesnt allow it.

you can check this answer  [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5162/how-to-allow-configurable-product-on-grouped-product)